# setup ftp .ssh directory with public/private key info with docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an helm-chart that references sftp key string:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: PUBLIC_KEY
      value: secretFromVault
    - name: PRIVATE_KEY
      value: secretFromVault
```

I have a `DockerFile` that sets up my user and creates an `.ssh` directory

```
RUN adduser -D -s /bin/bash -h /test_user test_user &&\
mkdir /test_user/.ssh/ &&\
chmod 700 /test_usr/.ssh/ &&
```

In this directory, I want to create the `id_rsa` file and input the private key string and create a `knownhost` file and input the reference of the public key so I can establishing remote connection target server?

How can I do this using dockerfile? Or is there a better way to do this? My sftp client code references these two files.

Comment: Could you mind clarifying the relationship in your question?
Are u using the image created by your `Dockerfile` to spin up the sftp server?

Comment: No, I have a service that uses jsch library to connect to remote server and I want to setup the auth files in the container to be referenced by the application

Comment: So, your container will run the Kubernetes pod with those keys right?

Comment: Yes. That’s correct

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making your secrets as environment variable, you need to mount them as a file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: keys
      mountPath: /home/test_user/.ssh
      subPath: id_rsa.pub
    - name: keys
      mountPath: /home/test_user/.ssh
      subPath: id_rsa
  volumes:
  - name: keys
    secret:
      secretName: secretFromVault
      defaultMode: 384
```

You will need to update the secret name from `PUBLIC_KEY` and `PRIVATE_KEY` to `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `VOLUME /test_usr/.ssh` to your Dockerfile and then mount a local directory to that volume. In the local directory you can generate the keys with `ssh-keygen` and the `knownhosts` if needed.

Comment: `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile mostly only has confusing side effects; you don't need it to mount files into the container (@RyanSiu's answer can work on an unmodified image, for example).